# Efficient aquarium cooler

Tags: aquarium, fish, water-parameters

I wonder if it'd be a good idea to cool an aquarium with an external source of water, e.g., pool water. Because my tank runs hot in summer (~30C) and needs to be brought down to 25C, I was thinking if it'd be a good idea to have the extra (plastic?) storage cooled by circulating a ring of (salt) pool water around it. Will this likely be effective? Plastic storage probably won't be ideal since it's an insulator.

Any idea appreciated.

Comment: related https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/25629/cooling-aquarium-with-aluminum-heat-sink

Comment: @trondhansen I don't think that first post addresses the possibility of using pool water for cooling.